# Windows Phone 8 WebView page isn't static (jQuery Mobile/PhoneGap)

Tags: jquery, css, cordova, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8

Apologies for the ambiguous title; however I am attempting to port our PhoneGap application which is working fine on Android and iOS onto Windows Phone 8 (written in jQuery Mobile/JavaScript, HTML and CSS3).

The most part of it worked (albeit I had to change a couple of bits but that was expected). One major problem I am having at the moment is getting the scrolling list functionality of our application working, and the signature capture (both I believe are related). I'm not too sure where the problem lies but when I scroll/sign, the entire page moves with my finger, and the individual elements do not pick up the touch-events. I am using iScroll, jQuery 1.7.2 and jQM 1.1.0; however, continue reading because the scrolling functionality *was* working (the signing feature has always been a problem)!

Before scrolling stopped working, I was having an issue with the gap between the footer bar and the bottom of the page:

[image: jQuery Mobile Gap]

One thing I was advised to do was to add the following bit of CSS; and it resolved the 'gap' issue:

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
    @-ms-viewport {
        width: 320px;
        user-zoom: fixed;
        max-zoom: 1;
        min-zoom: 1;
    }
}
```

[image: jQuery Mobile Gap Fix]

However, it then caused the scrolling features to become unresponsive. The entire page moves up/down but not the list element which is the opposite of what I want! I've tried adding the following but without luck:

```
-ms-touch-action: none;
```

I added this to my div element which contains the page. It stopped the page moving up and down! However the list remained unresponsive. However, if I remove both these CSS classes, then the scroll functionality works again, but that reintroduces the gap issue. The viewport CSS class is definitely the correct route I believe - but I cannot, for the life of me, get it to work the way I'd like it to.

If somebody could help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Comment: got the same question!

Comment: Can you post the html and CSS for the list ?
As i understood the full page moves up and down, yet you only want the list component to scroll, correct ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, @-ms-viewport doesn't support the zooming, so remove the zoom properties because they will generate parsing errors.
The supported properties are listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868813.aspx)

Second, try to add this rules to your CSS and use iScroll in your central container as you said you were doing

```
@-ms-viewport{width:device-width;}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -ms-content-zooming: none;
  -ms-touch-action: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this in your css and it will fix your footer.

```
[data-role=footer]{bottom:0; position:absolute !important; top: auto !important; width:100%;}
```